# SQL ON DELETE CASCADE vs. delete on business logic

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im using postgres with hibernate and i have two sql tables. "TABLE_2" have a manyToOne relationship to "TABLE_1".

```
CREATE TABLE "TABLE_1"
(
  "ID" bigint NOT NULL,
  "VALUE" bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_TABLE_1 " PRIMARY KEY ("ID" ),
)

CREATE TABLE "TABLE_2"
(
  "ID" bigint NOT NULL,
  "TABLE_1_ID" bigint,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_TABLE_2" PRIMARY KEY ("ID" ),
  CONSTRAINT "FK_TABLE_2-TABLE_1" FOREIGN KEY ("TABLE_1_ID")
      REFERENCES "TABLE_1" ("ID") MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE ????????
)
```

There may be a lot (millions) of entries in table 2 which are depending on a entry in table 1. When I delete a entry in table 1 all depending entries in table 2 should also be deleted. (Without out of memory exception)

I see two possible solutions to do that.

1. Using “ON DELETE CASCADE” in my table 2.
2. Implement some business logic to delete entries cascaded

x

```
while (true) {
    recTable2 = table2Dao.findForTable1(table1, 100);
    if (( recTable2 != null) && (recTable2 .size() > 0)) {
       for (Table2 Table2entry : recTable2) {
            table2Dao.remove(Table2entry);
        }
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

To avoid out of memory exception only 100 entries will be deleted in one step

Here my questions:

- When I use solution 1 with “ON DELETE CASCADE” what will happens if there are a lot of data to delete? Do i get out of memory exception or does postgres handle this “automatically”.
- When I use solution 2 with business logic the performance is very poor! Are there better ways to remove a lot of table entries??
- Which way would you prefer in general to delete cascaded table entries? Do it by business logic or do it by “ON DELETE CASCADE”?

Comment: keeping in mind, that if you went for the business logic approach you would have to run some queries against the database anyways I would go for the cascading delete, because improving performance for the other would involve tweaking your code as well as the database

Comment: Ok, but what happens on DB with "ON DELETE CASCADE" when deleting millions of cascaded entities? Without do it in steps for 100 entities i get a out of memory exception by using business logic!

Comment: I would say, try it. As such, normally an RDBMS is a lot better at handling these things than any developer in some high level language, databases are _made_ for these things. So if a cascading delete would cause a problem, I would focus on finding a solution in your database instead of in your code.

Comment: @Gatschet I would have wrote about that if I was sure; my gut would tell me that deleting millions of rows should not hurt too much since the foreign key will most likely be an int column with a clustered index on it; however I am pretty sure I never hit an `out of memory`exception when doing similar stuff, that only ever occurred to me when updating or doing really complex comparisons in my select statements that don't allow for index usage

Comment: Has a DBA (or anybody) tuned your PostgreSQL server? "PostgreSQL ships with a basic configuration tuned for wide compatibility rather than performance. Odds are good the default parameters are very undersized for your system." [From the wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question what's better when deleting a lot of entities (“Do it by business logic or do it by “ON DELETE CASCADE”), I wrote some test applications.

The first application stores 1 TABLE_1 entry and 100'000 TABLE_2 entities. All TABLE_2 entities have FOREIGN KEY of "TABLE_1_ID”enty.

Then I wrote two applications to delete all entries:

**Application 1:** (business logic approach)

First loads and deletes all TABLE_2 entities in a big for loop without using the “ON DELETE CASCADE” relationship. Then delete the entry in TABLE_1.

→ This application need 32 Seconds and around 600MB of heap memory

**Application 2:** ("ON DELETE CASCADE” approach)

Delete entry in TABLE_1 directly by using "ON DELETE CASCADE” (All entries in TABLE_2 will be automatically deleted)

→ This application need 0.067 Seconds and around 50MB of heap memory

So, after this little test I think the "ON DELETE CASCADE” approach is many times better. (500 times faster and need 12 times less memory)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have millions of records in the second table, better index the foreign key column. It will make a huge difference in the delete time.